# change div on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page with a div element (named apropos) diplayed. When the mouse is on a menu, I want the div to change to display another div named blog in the exact same spot.
For the moment, the blog div is displayed below the apropos one. The CSS for the two are the same.
An excerpt :

```
<a href="#" onMouseOver="show_blog()" onMouseOut="hide_blog()">Blog</a>

<div class="apropos"><p>lorem ipsum1</p></div
<div class="blog"><p>lorem ipsum2</p></div>

<script>
function show_blog() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("apropos")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementsByClassName("blog")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
}

function hide_blog() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("apropos")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementsByClassName("blog")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
}
</script>
```

Comment: `visibility` does not affect layout. Set `style.display = "none"` and `style.display = "block"`

Comment: I forgot it. See my comment on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `display` property, not `visibility`, because it leaves space like if the element still was there:

```
function show_blog() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("apropos")[0].style.display = "none";
    document.getElementsByClassName("blog")[0].style.display = "block";
}

function hide_blog() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("apropos")[0].style.display = "block";
    document.getElementsByClassName("blog")[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Note, I have to put `<div class="blog" style="display:none;">`.

Answer (score 0):

As answered, change the `visibility` to `display` property.

Just to add another approach to the answer, this could be easily solved with just css. Since the elements are siblings, you could use the sibling selector:

```css
#blogAnchor:hover ~ .blog
#blogAnchor:not(:hover) ~ .apropos{
  display: block;
}

#blogAnchor:hover ~ .apropos,
#blogAnchor:not(:hover) ~ .blog{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a id="blogAnchor" href="#">Blog</a>

<div class="apropos"><p>lorem ipsum1</p></div>
<div class="blog"><p>lorem ipsum2</p></div>
```